# Showing a correlation and its p-value as a color

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, p-value, heatmap

I want to convey in a heatmap how well are some correlations $[-1, 1]$ with its p-value $[0, 1]$. To normalize the plotting, the resulting numbers must be between $-1$ and $1$ and the sign must be the same as in the correlation in order to plot with a different color if the correlation is positive or negative. The higher the absolute value of a correlation is and the lowest the p-value, the higher must be the resulting number to be used for the heatmap.

How can I do that transformation to visualize easier the correlation and its p-value?

If $r = 0.8$ and $p = 0.04$, I want it with a value closer to $0$ than a correlation with $r = 0.8$ and $p = 0.03$. But a correlation with $r = -0.8$ and $p = 0.03$ must be minus the same number as for $r = 0.8$ and p-value $0.03$. Because usually low correlations tend to have high p-value (at least on my data) I would like to have the p-value and the correlation with the same influence on color.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want: If you have $r = .8$ with $p = .04$ then would you want that to be shown in a different colour/shade to $r= .8$ with $p = .03$?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I take it as an example for the question

Comment: I'll assume you already know that it's not really sensible to interpret p values like this... If you want to combine $r$ and $p$ into a single number then it seems like you'll have to decide the relative importance of each variable (i.e. decide if you want a difference of .1 in $r$ to have the same influence on colour as a difference of .1 in $p$, or a different influence)

Comment: I don't want to interpret p.values, I want to make easier to visualize high correlations with low p-values, in front of high correlations with high p-values

Comment: I made some edits to clarify the reason of the question. I hope that it can be reopened soon.

Comment: Just to be clear, re: your final sentence, you do know that the size of $r$ and $p$ are related? If $N$ is constant then the larger $r$ is, the smaller $p$ will be.

Comment: I've re-opened your q. as it seems you're interested in the principle rather than implementation using specific software.

Comment: @Ian_Fin Yes, more or less (I will read more about it)  I understand the relationship between $r$ an $p$. But in the heatmap each column can have a different N, I am actually adding it to the label of the axes to show that.

Comment: If these are all correlations from the same data set -- so that the sample size is constant for all pairs of correlations -- then it is impossible for the same $r$ value to be associated with more than one $p$ value, or for two $r$ values to have the same $p$ value.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your comment @Jake are you saying it is meaningless to do such visualization?  
Just in case I elaborate a bit more: The heatmap I plot compares one variable of a data set (A) with some other variables of another data set (B), each column is a variable of data set A, and I might have 28 samples or 18 of that variable, and the next one 15

Comment: What Jake is getting at is the fact that if $r_1=r_2$, and $N_1=N_2$, then the two $p$ values _must_ be equal. Similarly, if $r_1<r_2$ and $N_1=N_2$ then $r_1$ will _always_ have a larger $p$ value. Furthermore, if $r_1=r_2$, but $p_1<p_2$ then you know that $N_1>N_2$.

Comment: @Ian_Fin Right, and I see now that I didn't read the comments carefully enough and that this has already been addressed :p

Comment: If you really think you need to visualise something like this I keep coming back to thinking that what might make more sense is something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/263394009_fig6_Spearman-rank-correlation-heatmap-between-APAP-toxicity-and-metabolism-parameters-and-the) but where the size of the circle instead represents N. I would stay away from visualising p because, as I alluded to earlier, it encourages thinking that there's something meaningful about the difference between, e.g., $p=.03$ and $p=.04$

Comment: Using the shape of an ellipse to show the observed correlation & a colour scale to show the p-value is something I've seen, or dreamt.

Comment: @Ian See my current attempt to show, the data, I think it doesn't  encourages to consider that a lower p-value is meaningful than a higher one.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing together the correlation coefficients with the p-values using one dimension (hue) doesn't make sense. If the sample size is the same, then the same correlation coefficient will lead to the same p-value. If the sample size is not the same, then collapsing them both into a single variable is unhelpful and will rely on arbitrary and confusing choices.

There's a simple solution: as Ian_Fin suggests, just show both the correlation coefficient and the p-value using separate design elements. Any two of size, shape, colour, and text can be used to convey them separately. The `corrplot` package in R for visualising correlation matrices offers a range of plotting options and can be used for this. Or, since a correlation matrix is symmetric, you could also show the correlation coefficient elements above the diagonal and the p-values below it (or vice versa, as in [this example](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Naveed-Khan-21/publication/346107399/figure/fig2/AS:964711206113283@1607016483924/Matrix-of-Pearsons-Correlation-Coefficients-r-Left-Triangle-and-p-values-Right_W640.jpg)).

Answer (score -2):

I use the following transformation: I multiply the correlation measure by 1 minus the p-value: `cor.value * (1 - p.value)`. And the resulting heatmap looks like this:

[image]
The numbers in the heatmap are the correlation coefficient and inside the brackets the p-values. In the axes between parenthesis represent the number of variables of the datasets used.

Comment: Any reason the correlation value is not used without the p-value?

Comment: I thought it would help to distinguish some close correlation values but with different p-values, see the last column the last two rows only differ in 0.04 in the correlation but the p-value of one is 10^-3 and the other to 10^-9 this makes the color of one slightly clearer than the other.

Comment: One thing that really jumps out at me are the two -.28 correlations in the bottom right corner. The top is not significant at an $\alpha=.05$ level, while the bottom would be significant even at an $\alpha=.001$ level, and yet the difference between the two colours is almost imperceptible. If I have to inspect the $p$-values for two equal correlations to determine which is and which isn't significant then I'm not what the purpose is of having $p$ influence the colours.

Comment: The answer above could lead to unintended interpretations. For example: Case 1: R1 = 0.8, p1 = 0.001 Case 2: R2 = 0.81, p2 = 0.03, Then using your formula (R *(1-p)) Case 1: 0.7992
Case 2: 0.7857 You have made the weaker correlation appear stronger which could be misleading.

Comment: You might want to reconsider the use of white as your centre point. White is sometimes used in correlation matrix heatmaps to represent non-significance. In your case, a $r= .01$ with a $p=.01$ would be close to 0, and therefore white, while it would be significant at an $\alpha=.05$ level

Comment: Your example does illustrate what I said in my first comment to the question though: If you want to aggregate $r$ and $p$ you need to decide on the relative importance of each. In this formula, they have equal importance so a big difference in what is arguably the less interesting variable can warp differences in the more interesting one

Comment: Note that I want to display colors not numbers and use that number to take decisions. I doubt that this difference of 0.02 would make a big visual change. But I am open to suggestions on other formulas even not weighting  the p-value the same as the correlation.

Comment: The multiplication of a statistic by a complementary p-value looks *ad hoc*.  Is there some theoretical basis for it?

Comment: @Llopis The formula you ought to use probably depends on what information you want to convey and, perhaps more critically, what you want to do with the information. It's not obvious why you want to represent differences in $p$-values, when often the only use for a $p$-value is to see if it's below some $\alpha$-level.

Comment: @whuber No, I thought it would be easier spot interesting cells, Ian, I just want to plot it to spot interesting cells of that table. In the image I posted both the correlation and the p-value are showed, but for people it is easier to look for colors than to scan for huge tables with numbers.

Comment: But why wouldn't using `cor.value^3 * cos(p.value)` make it even easier to spot interesting cells?

Comment: @Scortchi Because I didn't thought about using cosine. That would be the kind of answer I am looking for.